# Disconnected Access DB to collect info then upload to sql database

Tags: sql, ms-access, connection

I am creating an Access Database that will reside on a Windows Tablet.

The user will take the tablet to locations where network and internet access aren't available, create entries into the local database on the tablet.

The database was developed on Sql Server 2008, then copied to local table to insure correct structure.

I can collect the data fine, my question is this:

When the tablet is back on the network, I want to use a button to upload the data stored locally to our SQL Server, then remove the data from the local database.

How do I connect the SQL Database (connection string info in VBA I assume - just don't know the syntax) and perform the upload when back on the network?

Thank you,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about synchronising a local sql database on a table (surface ?) to say web based sql server you might want to consider the sync framework - see this post for more information on its use in mobile

[mobile and sync framework](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/synchronizing-winrtsqlite-using-sync-framework-toolkit/)

Comment: I am not using web based sql at this time.